# $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$$

I tried substituting $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and then added the two integrals but got stuck. I got no idea how to proceed here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: expand the $\ln$ about $x=0$ and integrate term-by-term.